# elegant-admin template mobile nav toggle not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded an admin theme, after I put the css in my django statics the mobile toggle is no more showing. I went over all the CSS and js links (in the index template) they are linked to the right paths but the toggele is not showing.

here is the HTML and the CSS, please help.

```
<nav class="navbar top-navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- Logo -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                        <!-- Logo icon --><b>
                            <!--You can put here icon as well // <i class="wi wi-sunset"></i> //-->
                            <!-- Dark Logo icon -->
                            <img src="../assets/images/logo-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
                            <!-- Light Logo icon -->
                            <img src="../assets/images/logo-light-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="light-logo" />
                        </b>
                        <!--End Logo icon -->
                        <!-- Logo text --><span>
                            <!-- dark Logo text -->
                            <img src="../assets/images/logo-text.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
                            <!-- Light Logo text -->
                            <img src="../assets/images/logo-light-text.png" class="light-logo" alt="homepage" /></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <!-- End Logo -->
                <!-- ============================================================== -->
                <div class="navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <!-- toggle and nav items -->
                    <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <!-- This is  -->
                        <li class="nav-item hidden-sm-up"> <a class="nav-link nav-toggler waves-effect waves-light"
                                href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="ti-menu"></i></a></li>
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <!-- Search -->
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <li class="nav-item search-box"> <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-dark"
                                href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                            <form class="app-search">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search &amp; enter"> <a
                                    class="srh-btn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav my-lg-0">
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <!-- User profile and search -->
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-muted waves-effect waves-dark" href=""
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img
                                    src="../assets/images/users/1.jpg" alt="user" class="img-circle" width="30"></a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                        <!-- User profile and search -->
                        <!-- ============================================================== -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

<!-- Left Sidebar - style you can find in sidebar.scss  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<aside class="left-sidebar">
    <div class="d-flex no-block nav-text-box align-items-center">
        <span><img src="../assets/images/logo-icon.png" alt="elegant admin template"></span>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-dark ml-auto hidden-sm-down" href="javascript:void(0)"><i
                class="ti-menu"></i></a>
        <a class="nav-toggler waves-effect waves-dark ml-auto hidden-sm-up" href="javascript:void(0)"><i
                class="ti-menu ti-close"></i></a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(../../../assets/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(../../../assets/icons/themify-icons/themify-icons.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500,600,700");
.skin-default-dark {
  /*Theme Colors*/ }
  .skin-default-dark .topbar {
    background: #fff; }
    .skin-default-dark .topbar .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: #adb5bd; }
  .skin-default-dark .sidebar-nav ul li a.active, .skin-default-dark .sidebar-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #009efb; }
    .skin-default-dark .sidebar-nav ul li a.active i, .skin-default-dark .sidebar-nav ul li a:hover i {
      color: #009efb; }
  .skin-default-dark .sidebar-nav > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #009efb; }
    .skin-default-dark .sidebar-nav > ul > li.active > a i {
      color: #009efb; }
  .skin-default-dark .page-titles .breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item.active {
    color: #009efb; }
  .skin-default-dark .topbar .top-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand .dark-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
  .skin-default-dark .topbar .top-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand .light-logo {
    display: none; }
  .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar {
    background: #2b2f3a; }
    .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .user-pro-body a.link {
      color: #8991a9; }
    .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .nav-text-box {
      border-color: transparent;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
    .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li > a, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav ul li a {
      color: #8991a9;
      -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
      -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in;
      transition: 0.1s ease-in; }
      .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li > a i, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav ul li a i {
        color: #7f879b; }
      .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li > a:hover i, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li > a:hover, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav ul li a:hover i, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff; }
      .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li > a.active, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li > a.active i, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav ul li a.active, .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav ul li a.active i {
        color: #fff; }
    .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li.selected > a {
      color: #fff; }
      .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav > ul > li.selected > a i {
        color: #fff; }
    .skin-default-dark .left-sidebar .sidebar-nav ul li ul {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  .skin-default-dark .ps > .ps__scrollbar-y-rail > .ps__scrollbar-y {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .skin-default-dark.mini-sidebar .sidebar-nav #sidebarnav > li > ul, .skin-default-dark.mini-sidebar .sidebar-nav #sidebarnav > li:hover > a {
      background: #1f2023; } }
```

This is a django project but I have all static file in one folder but I'm just out of my dept it seems, I tried many things! The frustration for me is the downloaded files in their original folders work fine.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is most definitely cause of the first two imports in your CSS. Can you provide the path where the files are located and the path where your CSS is?

Comment: I updated the imports in the post for better readability. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two @impors in the CSS file, they are:

```
@import url(../../../assets/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(../../../assets/icons/themify-icons/themify-icons.css);
```

I just cut them from there and put them in the html like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'users/crm2/assets/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %} " rel="stylesheet">


 <link href="{% static 'users/crm2/assets/icons/themify-icons/themify-icons.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

That was it!